# Помогите не работает код jQuery!

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом,при нажатии на кнопку должен выводиться текст но такого не происходит
вот код :

```
$(".start-button2").click(function(){
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    $(".start").after("<div class='auther'></div>");
    $(".auther").html("<div class='auther-bg'></div><div class='auther-text'><div class='auther-back'>Назад</div></div>");
});
$(".auther-back").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда Вы вызываете

```
$(".auther-back").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

элемента с классом `auther-back` еще нет. Выборка `$(".auther-back")` - пустая, и обработчик ни к чему не прикрепляется.

Прикрепляйте обработчик события `"click"` для `.auther-back` к существующему элементу, используя делегирование:

```
$(document).on("click", ".auther-back", function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

Comment: @СашаГросул Вы же `".auther"` тоже позднее создаете :(.

Comment: Спасибо,помогло!)

Comment: @СашаГросул Пожалуйста. Успехов!